# React: transferring HTML elements to web worker to generate Pdf using jspdf and html2canvas

Tags: reactjs, web-worker, jspdf, html2canvas

I am currently creating a pdf file from html inside a react component using jspdf and html2canvas.  It works, but it can lock the browser when there's a lot of data.  So, i want to delegate this task to a web worker to do it in the background and not block the browser.

This is the way I do it **without** the worker:

```
handleExportToPdf = () => {
    const pages = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("client-report__container"));
    Promise.all(pages.map(p => html2canvas(p, { logging: false }))).then(canvases => {
        const pdf = new JsPDF({
            orientation: "l",
            unit: "in",
        });
        // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
        for (let i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) pdf.addPage();
            pdf.addImage(canvases[i].toDataURL("image/png"), "PNG", 0.25, 0, 11, 8);
        }
        pdf.save("report.pdf");
    });
};
```

This is modified to use web worker:

```
handleExportToPdf = () => {
        const pages = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("client-report__container"));
        this.reportWorker.postMessage(pages);

    };
```

However, i get this error when i try to run this:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': HTMLDivElement object could not be cloned.
```

This is the code in my worker:

```
export default () => {
    self.addEventListener("message", event => {
        console.log("in worker");
        const canvases = event.data;
        const pdf = new JsPDF({
            orientation: "l",
            unit: "in",
        });
        // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
        for (let i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) pdf.addPage();
            pdf.addImage(canvases[i].toDataURL("image/png"), "PNG", 0.25, 0, 11, 8);
        }
        pdf.save("report.pdf");
    });
};
```

Is there a way to transfer Html elements to web worker? Or, a better way to do this?
I tried just transferring the canvases, but that didn't work either.  Got the same error (HtmlCanvasElement).

Comment: Hello, could you try to do `const pages = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("client-report__container").cloneNode(true))` ?

Comment: @samb102 i tried that but it didnt' work :-/

Comment: does the error message changes or it's still `HTMLDivElement object could not be cloned` ?

Comment: Yes, it's still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out DOM elements will not work with [the structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm).  Images do, however, so I could simply transfer the canvas images instead of the canvas element.  Instead, I decided to parse the DOM elements to extract the data i needed and used pdfMake to create the pdf file (due to blurriness from using html2canvas/jsPDF).